# scala testing akka actors adding values to the db

Tags: scala, akka, actor, scalatest

I am trying to test run semi integration test with actors, that involve persisting to the db. the fooActor is adding kids to the db. but I have to wait till the persistence to the db will be completed using Thread.sleep :

```
"persist kids" in {
      fooActor ! addChildToParent(bar,foo)
      expectMsg("done")
      fooActor ! addChildToParent(buz,foo)
      expectMsg("done")
      Thread.sleep(2000)
      suggestionActor ! GetChildListForParent(foo)
      expectMsg(
        Some(List(bar,buz))
      )
    }
```

well this works fine, but I hate the fact that I have to use the Tread.sleep(2000). is there a way to minimize this effect ?

Comment: i would try synchronous testing (http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/testing.html#Synchronous_Unit_Testing_with_TestActorRef) or just avoid these types of tests altogether. I think Akka's testing scenarios are geared way more toward isolation/unit tests, not "semi-integration". If you want to do your own thing you will spend a lot of time fighting against the grain (Roland Kuhn's own answers on SO posts regarding this seem to indicate minimalism & carefully designed code with unit testing is the recommended usage of Akka). In my own project I have actor tests separate from repo tests.

Answer (score 2):

To minimize the effect, you could use `awaitAssert`

```
awaitAssert {
  suggestionActor ! GetChildListForParent(foo)
  expectMsg(
    Some(List(bar,buz))
  )
}
```

This [awaitAssert](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.4.1/index.html#akka.testkit.TestKit@awaitAssert(a:=%3EAny,max:scala.concurrent.duration.Duration,interval:scala.concurrent.duration.Duration):Unit) retries the given block as long as the expected message is not received. It continues retrying until either the block does not throw an exception (in which case the test succeeds) or until the max duration expires (in which case the test fails). The max duration and interval are optional arguments of `awaitAssert`.